# Github website commit author username is different to one shown in git log

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am at my wits' end with this. I've been working on and IntelliJ project using a new PC, and have discovered that when I push any commits the author name displays my old username (I'd changed it a few months ago, before I got this PC). No matter what I do, however, I cannot seem to be able to get Github to show the correct author username.

Looking at the git log in cmd shows the correct username,

```
git remote show origin
```

shows the correct fetch and push URLs as

```
https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<project>.git
```

and IntelliJ's Git commit history window shows the correct username as well, but when I make any commit it still shows the old username on Github.

I have also tried the following:

- Rebasing before the commits with the wrong author and running

`git commit --amend --author "\<username> <<email-address>>"`

on the commits in question followed by a force push (the commit does force push and shows up as modified but the author remains the same)

- Setting both the local and global git config with:

  `git config --global user.name <username>`

  `git config --global user.email <email-address>`
- Checking the .gitconfig file shows the correct username
- Removing and re-adding my GH credentials in Intellij
- Creating a new project in Intellij and pushing it to Github
- Creating a new repository using Git bash and pushing it to Github
- Restarting my computer (you never know)

Is there anything else I can try? I can't think of any reason why these commits are showing up with the wrong username when it was a fresh install on a new machine, and none of the advice I could find anywhere seems to work. Any and all ideas welcome!

Comment: GitHub shows usernames from email, so if the user has configured a different display name on <https://github.com/settings/profile>, GitHub will show that instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things going on here.

First, in your commits, there is a name and an email.  [As outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatshouldIputincodeusernamecode), what's in `user.name` is typically a personal name, not a username.  Nothing in `user.name` has any affect on any account or authentication whatever, so there's no reason to set it to a username.  For example, the maintainer of Git uses "Junio C Hamano".  `user.email` is used for configuring the email address in the commit.

What you see on GitHub is a GitHub username, and the association with your commits is purely based on the email address in the commits (usually, the setting of `user.email` when you made the commit).  For example, if I use the email address I normally use at home, GitHub will associate those with the user bk2204.  This correspondence is set up in the settings, and only one account can be associated with an email address at a time.

If you want your commits to be associated with a different account, then they must use an email address associated with that account.  If you create commits where the email address is not associated with any account, then GitHub will not show an account and will instead show the value set as the (personal) name in the commit (e.g., "Pat Roe").

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying the user.name property for me! However my issue is that, while I've authenticated with the correct username/address, the new commits continue to be attributed to my old username as if it were a different contributor, and clicking the username directs me to an empty account with seemingly no activity, which, if the documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/changing-your-github-username#links-to-your-previous-profile-page is correct, should actually return a 404.

Comment: Ah. I have discovered the problem. The email address I was wholeheartedly convinced I was using was, in fact, not the one associated with my GH account! Have changed it out and it's working correctly now, and explains the strange commits, however it is odd that the other account (which I recall now making to save the username) is able to make commits to the repository despite not having access rights to the repository.

Comment: GitHub allows you to push commits that your account did not create.  Many workflows, like those used by Git and Linux, involve a dedicated maintainer who accepts patches from other people and pushes them up to a single location, which means that the maintainer will push commits they didn't create to a repository the authors don't have access to modify.